# Nested react router component doesn't load/render on page reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have been learning react for past few weeks. And now I'm having an issue that when I reload the page using browser reload button, instead of reloading the component , the component just disappear (and is blank. No error is visibly thrown, but not even the component that's supposed to render on that route shows up.) while other  header/footer component loads fine. While same type up set up on other link on nav bar, reload is just working fine.
 
[1]: https://react---frontend.herokuapp.com/ this is the link for my dummy react website. 
Here in this page we can see some post. Clicking on the post takes the user to post details page.
[2]: https://react---frontend.herokuapp.com/post/ (this link doesn't load directly, it's just for refrence) 
Now here inserting post specific comment is just working fine and it shows up instantly without reloading the page. But when reload button is pressed the post detail component just disappear.

This is my Index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store = {store} >
        <BrowserRouter >
            <PersistGate persistor={persistor}> 
                <App />
            </PersistGate>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is my App.js

```
render(){
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Header />
            <Navbar title = "React Blog" />
            <Body />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is my body.js. These routes support browser reload.

```
return (
    <div>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path = "/" component = {PostIndex} />
                <Route path = "/contact" component = {ContactIndex} />
                <Route path = "/about" component = {AboutIndex} />
                <Route path = "/auth" component = {AuthIndex} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </div>
);
```

This is postindex.js. The showpost component is the culprit.It doesnot load when page is reloaded.

```
return(//showpost should have been loaded when refreshed
    <div>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path = "/" exact component = {Post} />
                <Route path = "/post" component = {Showpost} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </div>
);
```

This is showpost.js

```
render() { //this page is no re-rendering when refreshed

    const comment = this.props.post.comment.map(function(comment){
           return <div key = {comment.id}>{comment.body}</div>
    })

    console.log(this.props.post)

    return(
        <div className='container'>
            <div><h3>{this.props.post.title}</h3></div>
            <div>{this.props.post.body}</div><hr/>
            <h3><label>Comment</label></h3>
            <CreateComment/>
            <hr/>
            {comment}
        </div>
    );
}
```

For every switch I have wrapped with BrowserRouter. Is that a usual way to do it? As for state I am using redux-persist.
And how can I make https://react---frontend.herokuapp.com/post/id
load directly using url.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment

Comment: This problem is nothing to do with deployment, cause it exists in local environment also

Comment: It's ALL about this... did you read [this section](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing) carefully? Do you know how one `index.php` in f.e. WordPress can serve multiple urls? Virtual routes problem should be obvious for everyone in web development - even not worth a separate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to wrap with Router in the root

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
<Router>
    <App />
</Router>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I have tried, but that postindex.js wouldn't load any component.

Comment: do you have a github repo link or a codesandbox? It would help for me to look at everything together

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I'm having the same issue while trying to switch from HashRouter to BrowserRouter. I did the above, updated historyApiFallback, added wildcard in my express setup for index.html; and still no luck. The component won't render on refresh..